# On manipulating date or time the format changes

Tags: vba, date, excel

**This must be a cakewalk for regular VB programmer writing Excel macros.**

I am trying to convert negative time in **-HH:-MM:-SS** format to **HH:MM:SS** and swapping the values of the previous two columns(which are timestamps) in the same row (only if negative date is found).

The date is getting converted from negative to positive but for eg. from "**-01:-05:-14**" it changes to "**1:05:14 AM**" (first '0' missing and 'AM' added at the end) instead of "**01:05:14**".

Also the format of timestamps on getting swapped changes from "**04/01/2014 04:31:31 AM**" to "**4/1/2014  4:31:31 AM**" (intial '0' missing) .
Please help me in resolving this? Any new approach is also welcome.

I'm using the following code:

```
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
Dim temp As Integer
Dim TimeText As String
Dim TestArray() As String 'Array to get the negative time, if any
temp = 0
Dim actualRow As Integer
Dim totalRows As Integer
Dim totalCols As Integer

Dim i As Integer
Dim tempSwap As String

totalRows = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
totalCols = Application.CountA(Range("1:1"))

For row = 2 To totalRows
actualRow = row - temp
For col = 2 To totalCols
TimeText = ActiveSheet.Cells(actualRow, col).Value

If Left(TimeText, 1) = "-" Then 'initial space and "-" sign

        TestArray() = Split(TimeText, "-")



        For i = 1 To UBound(TestArray)

          MsgBox (TestArray(i))

        Next

        ActiveSheet.Cells(actualRow, col).Value = TestArray(1) + TestArray(2) + TestArray(3) ' We know that there will be 3 array elements and TestArray(0)=""
    'SWAPPING THE COLUMN VALUES
    tempSwap = ActiveSheet.Cells(actualRow, col - 1).Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(actualRow, col - 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(actualRow, col - 2).Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(actualRow, col - 2).Value = tempSwap

    temp = temp + 1

End If
Next col
Next row
```

Comment: Suppose the end result is stored in a variable called "ConvertedTime` then use this `Format(ConvertedTime,"HH:MM:SS")`

Comment: Also ensure that the column in the excel sheet is also formatted as Time (`"HH:MM:SS"`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have cells like:

**-01:-05:-14**

Select them and run:

```
Sub FixTime()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        With r
            v = Replace(Trim(.Text), "-", "")
            .Clear
            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
            .Value = v
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```